# Fire onchange event if value is not changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop-down like this:

```
<select name="test" onchange="test();">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

function test()
{
    alert('hi');
}
```

on page load value 1 got selected, I want the onchange event to fire if the user selects 1 again. How can I achieve this functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

This does not cause `onchange` to fire, but can be made to do whatever you wanted to do `onchange`, regardless of which `<option>` was clicked.

HTML:

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("[name='test'] > option").click(function() {
        alert("value clicked");
    });
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrrEx/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select>
   <option value="apple">apple</option>
   <option value="mango">mango</option>
   <option value="orange">orange</option>
   <option value="banana">banana</option>
 </select>



 $(document).ready(function(){
 var select = $("select");

 var screenDif = 0;
 select.bind("hover", function (e) {
    screenDif = e.screenY - e.clientY;
 });
 select.bind("click", function (e) {
    var element = $(e.target);
    var eventHorizon = screenDif + element.offset().top + element.height() -     $(window).scrollTop();
    if (e.screenY > eventHorizon)
        alert(this.value);
    });
   });
```

Here is the Demo http://jsfiddle.net/wFc8X/

I hope you wanted to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind a click event on the option and trigger a change event on click

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

$(function() {
    BindClickHandlers($('select'));
    $('select').on('change', OnChange);
})
function OnChange (event) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        BindClickHandlers(event.currentTarget);
    }, 0);
}
function BindClickHandlers(selectObject) {
    $(selectObject).find('option').off('click');
    $(selectObject).find(':selected').on('click', function () {
        $(selectObject).trigger('change');
    });
}
```

Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jNnWn/1/)